# React Project-When click and move mouse, div tries to move

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have problem about CSS. I'm working on a React-Pixel project now. When I click a grid and move my mouse, i expect fill hovered grids. This works. But sometimes when i click a grid and move my mouse, div tries to move and my cursor turns no-drop. And if mouse turns no-drop, i can't fill the grids. My mouse act like I'm try to move my grid. I think this is a CSS problem. Can you help me? Thank you

this is live demo: https://dazedblack.github.io/react-pixel-app/
this is my code: https://github.com/dazedblack/react-pixel-app

Comment: You need to post code sample that reproduces the problem, we cannot quess the problem othervice

Comment: hi. i shared code and live demo. you can try... im newbie so sorry for this